# xPages - want to override xpage generated CSS

Tags: css, xpages

I turned off the theme in the XSP properties and have a CSS set for my xpage.  I'm finding some of the page elements are getting a CSS setting from a dijit CSS.  Where is this coming from and how do I turn it off?  Some of the fields/labels are correct while others are not.  I'm including the firebug log for a FilteringSelect field I have that is not displaying correctly.  I've searched for answers for this and spent a lot of time on it but can't figure it out.

```
.tundra .dijitInputContainer input {
    margin: 0 0.1em;
}
.dijitSelect input, .dijitTextBox input {
    float: left;
}
.dijitInputInner {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border: 0 none !important;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
.dijitReset {
    border: 0 none;
    color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-feature-settings: inherit;
    font-kerning: inherit;
    font-language-override: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-size-adjust: inherit;
    font-stretch: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-synthesis: inherit;
    font-variant: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
input, select {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That CSS will be pulled from the relevant Dojo version, because you're using a Dojo component (the FilteringSelect). You can include the relevant CSS files independently of OneUI. If you disable aggregation in xsp.properties (you may need to clean the project), you should be able to see which files you need to include.

Comment: What I did was to figure out which of the dojo variables was setting my property and include that exact variable in my CSS and use the !important on the variable, example: .dijitInputInner, I set the border and background colors to override the default.